# Error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'inputInfoLivro'

Tags: c

```
void listarcaixas(int opcaixa, inputInfoLivro, inputInfoRevista){
int quantidadeobra = inputInfoLivro(L) + inputInfoRevista(R);
int i;

for(i=0; i<quantidadeobra; i++){
    
    if(rvist.caixa == opcaixa && lvro.caixa == opcaixa){
        printf("\n Titulo: %s\n", rvist.titulo);
        printf("\n Autor: %s\n", rvist.autor);
        printf("\n Editora: %s\n", rvist.editora);
        printf("\n Edicao: %s\n", rvist.edicao);
        printf("\n ISBN: %s\n", rvist.isbn);
        printf("\n Quantidade: %s\n", rvist.quantidade);
        printf("\n Caixa: %d", rvist.caixa);
        printf("\n ******************************************** \n \n");
        
        printf("\n Titulo: %s\n", lvro.titulo);
        printf("\n Autor: %s\n", lvro.autor);
        printf("\n Editora: %s\n", lvro.editora);
        printf("\n Edicao: %s\n", lvro.edicao);
        printf("\n ISBN: %s\n", lvro.isbn);
        printf("\n Quantidade: %s\n", lvro.quantidade);
        printf("\n Caixa: %d", lvro.caixa);
        printf("\n ******************************************** \n \n");
            
    }
}
}
```

estou recebendo os erros -> [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'inputInfoLivro'

```
                        [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'inputInfoRevistas'
```

opcaixa é uma variavel global que o usuario insere.

os dois input são funções que retornaram um valor inteiro.

não coloquei o codigo inteiro pq ta bem grande.

Comment: Por acaso `inputInfoLivro` e `inputInfoRevista` são nomes de funções que você quer passar como parâmetro? Se for não é uma sintaxe válida. Talvez utilizar ponteiro para função possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: ainda não aprendi a usar ponteiros...

Comment: é isso mesmo que quero, passar como parametro

Comment: Não conheço uma solução direta, da maneira como tentou, sem a utilização de ponteiros.

Answer (score 0):

Falta o tipo da variável que tu recebe na função

void listarcaixas (int opcaixa, 'aqui' inputInfoLivro, 'e_aqui' inputInfoRevista)